# Invalid authenticity token when POSTing to a Rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a web application that gets & stores some data through a Rails API.

When I try to "post" to the Rails API, I get an error `ActionController::InvalidAuthenticityToken`.  I know one option is to simply disable the authenticity token requirement on my Rails controller.

Is it possible to have my web app providing a correct authenticity token when it calls the Rails API?  How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

2 Part answer for you here.

First if you are going to be using Rails as an API I would recommend you use another way of validating that the user making the request is actually the user they say they are such as creating a unique token upon account creation or login that can be returned in the initial response and provided as a HTTP header in subsequent requests. If you are worried about the security of this you could optionally base64 encode the key plus some other value and decode it server side before comparison.

If you still wish to use the CSRF method baked in to Rails you can do so as long as the user is making a request from the webapp using AJAX or whatever. If you have the `csrf_meta_tags` ERB in the header of your layout file you can get the  value and set it in the `X-CSRF-Token` HTTP header. Using jQuery it may look something like:

```
$.ajaxPrefilter(function(options, originalOptions, xhr) {
  var token = $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content');
  if (token) xhr.setRequestHeader('X-CSRF-Token', token);  
});
```

This would cause it to be added to every ajax request made using jQuery.